# Rotate camera display to show x+ axis instead of z+

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone,

I have a standard camera display with a calibrated camera info file and it's displaying everything correctly, but instead of looking up the z-axis I would like to look into the direction of the positive x-axis.
My guess would be to create an extra frame (like [this](http://wiki.ros.org/tf/Tutorials/Adding%20a%20frame%20%28C%2B%2B%29)?) and rotate it or something like that?
Does anyone have any pointers for me? Thanks a lot!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/264095/rotate-camera-display-to-show-x+-axis-instead-of-z+/) by [frizzle](https://answers.ros.org/users/30128/frizzle/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2017-06-18

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [AndyZe](https://answers.ros.org/users/21281/andyze/) on 2017-06-19**:
Are you doing this to be compatible with the look_at_pose package?

Do you mean, you have a robot model and you want to rotate the camera in the robot model? Or, you want to change the frame that the camera data gets reported in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You could broadcast a tf from C++ (or python), but it's easier to use a static_transform_publisher http://wiki.ros.org/tf#static_transform_publisher

For your transform xyz would be 0 0 0, and then 0 1.570796 0 for yaw pitch roll (or play with the numbers until it comes out right).

---

Originally posted by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) with karma: 8729 on 2017-06-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1